# Strapi CMS v4 - How to create a new Strapi Collection Types from an existing one

Tags: content-management-system

I am currently using Strapi CMS v4. I have created a Strapi CMS Collection Type (Collection Type A). I want duplicate Collection Type A and name it Collection Type B. Unfortunately, I cannot find any guidance on the Strapi website on how to do it. I can duplicate a content record within the same Collection Type, but that is not what I want.

Is it possible to create a new Collection Type from an existing one in Strapi v4?